# Create static variable in Browser Helper Object

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, bho, dllexport

I have a DLL that I load into Internet Explorer as a C++ Browser Helper Object (BHO). I want to create a unique GUID every time the browser is restarted. I tried 3 different solutions:

1) Create a global static variable. However, it seems opening a new tab creates a new process, and that variable state isn't passed across the different loaded instances of the plugin.

2) I tried creating a singleton class where I maintain a single object that returns the GUID. Didn't work either, possibly because of the same reasons as [1].

3) Lastly, I tried to set a session cookie (using InternetSetCookie). However the session cookie is per process, which basically means that opening a new tab doesn't pass on the session cookie.

Is there an easy way to share state between all the instances of a BHO (i.e DLL). I read about __declspec(dllexport), but not sure if that is the right solution for this problem. That seems to be more towards sharing variables between different DLL's. I, on the other hand, have multiple instances of the same DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared data segment and create variables under this segment.
These variables can be accessed across processes.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// The following variable is shared across all processes 
#pragma data_seg("SHARED_SEG") // Begin shared data segment
LONG gCounter = 0;
#pragma data_seg() // End the shared data segment and default back to the normal data segment behavior.
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:SHARED_SEG,RWS")
```